# Changing between var and val in Scala leads to logical checks behaving differently

Tags: scala

I was working with Project Euler [Problem 4](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) (finding the largest palindrome formed from the product of two three-digit numbers), and produced the solution `euler4_1`, which uses a variable `cand`. The function runs as expected, iterating through all pairs `(i, j)` and only replacing `cand` with a bigger palindrome.

```
def euler4_1(): Int = {

    var cand=0

    for(i <- 100 until 999){
        for(j <- 100 until i){
          if (((i*j).toString.reverse == (i*j).toString)&&(i*j>cand)){
            cand=i*j
            println(cand)
            }
        }
    }

    return cand
    }

    /** 
    ...
    666666
    678876
    696696
    749947
    819918
    824428
    828828
    861168
    888888
    906609
     */
```

However, initializing `cand` as a `var` instead of a `val` seems to mess things up - a number of palindromes which are smaller than the current best are also printed out.

```
def euler4_2(): Int = {

    val cand=0

    for(i <- 100 until 999){
        for(j <- 100 until i){
          if (((i*j).toString.reverse == (i*j).toString)&&(i*j>cand)){
            val cand=i*j
            println(cand)
            }
        }
    }

    return cand
    }

    /** 
    ...
     601106
     650056
     853358
     141141
     282282
     119911
     906609
     514415
     580085
     */
```

What's happening in the second code sample, labelled `euler4_2`?

[Comments on how to make the code more idiomatic in scala are also appreciated].

Comment: `i*j>cand` have different result if `val cand`.

Comment: The second snippet has **two different** values named `cand` with different scopes. The inner one shadows the outer one.

Comment: thanks @n.m. Is there a way to avoid `vals` with my code as written, or do I need a major overhaul? I'm trying to force myself to think in a functional way here.

Comment: The idiomatic Scala way would be to use a "for comprehension" to build the max value in a monadic way (no vars) but I'm not too well versed in this. I'd ask a different question, appropriately titled.

Answer (score 4):

As n.m. pointed out in the comments, the problem is that you have two different `val`'s named `cand`. If you want to write this in functional style, without any `var`'s, use `foldLeft` and pass `cand` through each iteration:

```
(100 until 999).foldLeft(0) { (cand, i) =>
  (100 until i).foldLeft(cand) { (cand, j) =>
    val product = i * j
    val productS = product.toString
    if (productS.reverse == productS && product > cand) {
      println(product)
      product
    } else cand
  }
}
```

Comment: By the way, swapping conditions in `productS.reverse == productS && product > cand` *might* lead to a better performance.

Comment: True, but even better would be putting the calls to `toString` and `reverse` inside an `if (product > cand)`. There are a lot of optimizations that could be done here. My intention was only to show OP how to write idiomatic code, not redesign their algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> (for (i <- 100 until 999 ;
     |       j <- 100 until i;
     |       ij = i * j;
     |       ijs = ij.toString if ijs == ijs.reverse
     |      ) yield ij
     | ).max
res0: Int = 906609
```

would be the most obvious (to me) idiomatic functional-style implementation using comprehensions. Not sure about efficiency though.